# Cannot configure @ElementCollection to work as needed

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have the following Postgres DB Tables:

```
isopod=# select * from users;
 id | username | password | registered_at |       isopods        |                badges                
----+----------+----------+---------------+----------------------+--------------------------------------
  1 | mike     | mike     | now           | ISO.C.001, ISO.A.001 | badge1, badge2
(1 row)

isopod=# select * from isopods;
    id      | name  | size  | generation | type  | rarity |  icon  
----+-------+-------+------------+-----------------+--------+--------
  ISO.C.001 | AMBER | SMALL | CUBARIS    | type1 | RARE   | icon01
(1 row)
```

And I am trying to connect my Java classes to this DB. Everything works fine for single Strings, but I face problems configuring my `private List<String> isopods`.

My Java User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String registeredAt;
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="isopods", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
    private List<String> isopods = new ArrayList<>();
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Badge> badges;
```

My Java Isopod class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "isopods")
public class Isopod implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id; //ISO.C.001
    private String name;
    private String size;
    private String generation;
    private String type;
    private String rarity;
    private String icon;
```

My goal is to connect Isopod ID with User isopods list. Or even better refactor User's `List<String> isopods to List<Isopod>`
I have tried different combinations for `@CollectionTable` but nothing works.
With the above setup the error is the following:

```
2023-04-30 12:30:51.284 ERROR 30955 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column isopods0_.isopods does not exist
```

Can someone please explain me what I do wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You should never store passwords in plain text. Use a one way hashing function and store that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema looks *extremely* weird. That's not how associations are supposed to be represented in relational databases. Instead, you should have a separate association table holding associations between users and isopods.

Anyway, JPA mappings can't handle this sort of (bad) thing. You'll have to map the `isopods` column as a regular basic type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I' m not sure how I should structure my DB, any guideline would be appreciated. As far as I understand, I need 1 more table holding associations, but I am not sure if this needs to be a java class too or not? I' ll keep searching thanks!

Comment: Why don't you let Hibernate generate your schema, and look at what it generates? Hibernate will produce a sane relational schema, which you can use as a model. You can set `jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=create`.